# Regex stops working at 23 characters, but only if I pass in a string literal

Tags: c++

I've been trying to narrow down this very strange behavior that I noticed. Here's the code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

struct Scanner {
  std::string::const_iterator read_head;
  std::string::const_iterator eof;

  Scanner(std::string const& program) {
    read_head = program.cbegin();
    eof = program.cend();
  }
};

bool scan(Scanner const& scanner) {
  using std::regex_constants::match_continuous;
  static std::smatch match;

  std::regex regex = std::regex("a+");
  return std::regex_search(scanner.read_head, scanner.eof, match, regex, match_continuous);
}

int main() {
  std::string str1 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"; // 22 a's
  std::string str2 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"; // 23 a's
  Scanner s1(str1);
  Scanner s2(str2);
  Scanner s3("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"); // 22 a's
  Scanner s4("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"); // 23 a's

  bool token1_found = scan(s1);
  bool token2_found = scan(s2);
  bool token3_found = scan(s3);
  bool token4_found = scan(s4);

  std::cout << std::boolalpha << token1_found << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << token2_found << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << token3_found << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << token4_found << std::endl;
}
```

I would expect all four of these to show `true`, but bizarrely, I get:

```
true
true
true
false
```

It only seems to do this if I use the struct. I tried writing a function which did the same thing but by passing in either the string or the iterators directly, and everything behaved as expected in those cases (I didn't get this inexplicable `false`).

Does anybody know what's going on here?

---

**EDIT:**
I attempted to fix the problem, which according to @Geoffroy, is that `Scanner` is not taking ownership of the string. This is what I tried:

```cpp
struct Scanner {
  std::string program;
  std::string::const_iterator read_head;
  std::string::const_iterator eof;

  Scanner(std::string program) : program(program) {
    read_head = program.cbegin();
    eof = program.cend();
  }
};
```

but to no avail. Interestingly enough, when I do this, I get

```
true
false
true
false
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Oh, but if I change

```cpp
bool scan(Scanner const& scanner)
```

to

```cpp
bool scan(Scanner scanner)
```

then I get

```
true
true
true
true
```

Does anyone know why that might be? I assumed that `s1` - `s4` would exist until the end of `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Scanner` should own the string it uses, as you're using iterator to a temporary object otherwise.

It works when passing `str1` and `str2` as the objects still exists, but in the case of the string literals it's an undefined behavior.

Comment: I tried to solve this by saving the string in the `Scanner` struct, but the issue persisted.

Comment: @MichaelDorst how did you "save" it? You should take ownership (i.e. copy or move) of the string to be sure there's no problem

Comment: @MichaelDorst `read_head = this->program.cbegin();`, idem for `eof`, or you're getting an iterator to a temporary -> UB

Comment: =O ohh. Wow that does make sense. And it explains the weird errors I was still having with my actual project.

Answer (score 1):

@Geoffroys answer is entirely correct, you are keeping addresses of temporary `std::string` variables and that is UB.

I was curious why 22 chars worked and 23 did not.
As it turns out, the libcxx `std::string` implementation decides between two representations [based on whether `strlen(input) < sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(char*) - 1`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/da6e915c73f231074dc88f8a952a8273da0ca06b/include/string#L735-L751). On a 64-bit system, this condition is different for 22 and 23 characters.

So the 23-character version accesses recently-freed heap memory, so my guess is that the string there is reallocated by one of the intermediate expressions.

EDIT: The decision on which storage strategy to make is [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/da6e915c73f231074dc88f8a952a8273da0ca06b/include/string#L1755-L1759) and it is called from several constructors, among which the [`const char *` constructor](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/da6e915c73f231074dc88f8a952a8273da0ca06b/include/string#L1802).

EDIT 2: [This talk on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPR8h4-qZdk) describes the short string optimization and how Facebook's `fbstring` works. It also shows that libstdc++ short strings (anno 2016) had a capacity of only 15 characters while being 32 bytes long.

Comment: Nice work! Is it platform specific or did you find anything about that in the standards too?

Comment: Interesting! I think you may have posted the wrong link though, because a text search for `strlen` on that page yields nothing.

Comment: @Geoffroy it is specific to the STL used and architecture. The standard do not say anything about the representation of stirngs i guess. I did not check, but I'm pretty sure libstdc++ and MSVC have a different strategy.

Comment: @MichaelDorst It is called as `traits_type::length` in several places, I linked to one in my edit.